# I am unable to link a JSP button to controller in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass the control to controller by a JSP button click. When i am clicking on the button it is going to error with a change in URL.  Please help me on the same.

Please refer my code and suggest me how to resolve this problem of mine.

JSP CODE:

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>

   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="/upload">
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> Name: <input
            type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> <input type="submit"
            value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SpringMVController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you got? Post it in the question.

Comment: Now it is working, but i am getting access denied to upload the file.

Comment: please tell me where to update the file upload path name, in the spring application